# Remotely, programmatically control an iPhone from a GNU/Linux computer

Tags: linux, iphone

From a Debian GNU/Linux system, using any sort of technology to communicate with the phone (even if jailbreaking the device was required), if I had an iPhone plugged into the system via USB, how could I simulate touching the screen at an arbitrary position on the screen?

e.g. I have an app with a big button. How could I programmatically press that button?